# PHP 7 Location on 1and1

Tags: php, composer-php, hosting, php-7

I am looking to setup composer on 1and1 hosting to run under PHP7. Can anyone advise where this is located on the server.

It appears that it should be at `/usr/lib/php7.0` however there is nothing there.

has anyone had experience of this?

Comment: Can't you install a locally composer?

Comment: This is needed for a build tool. The question is more where the php7 binary is